# glibc 2.14 install error selinux.c: error: libaudit.h no such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, upgrade, glibc

Trying to install **glibc 2.14** following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299665) solution.

but I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it and can't find much online

```
selinux.c:37:23: error: libaudit.h: No such file or directory
selinux.c: In function ‘log_callback’:
selinux.c:138: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘audit_log_user_avc_message’
selinux.c:138: error: ‘AUDIT_USER_AVC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
selinux.c:138: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
selinux.c:138: error: for each function it appears in.)
selinux.c: In function ‘audit_init’:
selinux.c:152: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘audit_open’
make[2]: *** [/home/me/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build/nscd/selinux.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/local/home/me/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/nscd'
make[1]: *** [nscd/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/local/home/me/glibc_install/glibc-2.14'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Append `--without-selinux` to your `configure` command or install the `-dev` packages of SELinux and libaudit for your distribution.

You should probably install a newer version of `glibc`, though. Installing old versions on a new system is dangerous.